# Как распарсить 2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:0 ? python

Tags: python, дата

Как распарсить вот эту строку "2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:00" отдельно на **год-месяц-день**, отдельно на **час:минута:секунда**?

То есть, должно быть:

дата: 2022-08-20

время: 20:30:00

Comment: А куда потерялась ещё одна цифра в конце последнего числа?

Comment: [Что делать с ответами на вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Да, увидел, походу, последний ноль не скопировал. Спасибо.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

У вас дата и время в формате ISO, поэтому можно воспользоваться функцией `datetime.fromisoformat()`

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_string = '2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:00'
dt = datetime.fromisoformat(dt_string)
print(dt.date())  # 2022-08-20
print(dt.time())  # 20:30:00
```

Comment: Есть нюанс. Если Вы приведете строку в соответствие со строкой в задании, то-есть вместо `2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:00` используете `2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:0` как написано в задании, то Ваш код выдаст ошибку

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за помощь!

Comment: Последний ноль не скопировал, сорян)

Comment: а не подскажите, если мне нужно, чтобы   3 часа прибавилось(время по Гринвичу +3), то есть например было не 20:30, а 23:30, как реализовать??

Comment: `dt = datetime.fromisoformat(dt_string) + timedelta(hours=3)`. 
Не забудьте так же импортировать `timedelta` из `datetime`

Answer (score 5):

Предлагаю использовать парсер из библиотеки `python-dateutil` (*Кстати она используется в pandas*)

`pip install python-dateutil`

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse

x = parse('2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:0')

y = x.date()
z = x.time()

print(y, z, sep='\n')
# 2022-08-20
# 20:30:00
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Ожидаемо, что длина этой строки всегда одинакова, поэтому как один из вариантов - брать значения срезом

```
x = "2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:0"
date = x[0:10]
time = x[11:19]

print('Дата: ' + date)
print('Время: ' + time)
```

**Вывод:**

```
Дата: 2022-08-20
Время: 20:30:00
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за помощь!

Answer (score 3):

Я бы разделил на то, что до "T" и после. Оставшееся на то, что до "+" и после. Первые два разделения и есть дата и время.

```
x = '2022-08-20T20:30:00+00:0'

parts = x.split('T')

date = parts[0]
print(date)

time = parts[1].split('+')[0]
print(time)
```

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Это стандартный формат даты. Зачем его вручную разбирать?

Comment: Согласен, но ТС попросил разобрать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за помощь!